# Router with vpn client do not forward dns requests to the connected devices

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, internal-dns

I have a problem with my router forwarding dns requests to it's clients.

My setup is as follows. I have an ISP provider configured on my router and a vpn client connected. In the vpn's network there is a local dns server that has some of our internal records. My computer is connected to the router and I'm in its local network. I'm able to `ping` by IP address, but hen I try to `ping` with the domain name (which is a record in the vpn's local dns server) it says:

`Ping request could not find host reg.unimar.datapan.si. Please check the name and try again.`

The `nslookup` command fails too:

```
> nslookup my.domain.com
Server:  MI-MINI
Address:  192.168.0.1

*** MI-MINI can't find my.domain.com: Non-existent domain
```

I went to my router settings, and found one that was very promising `Obtaining DNS from VPN Server:`. There are 3 options - `No`, `Add to existing list` and `Replace all existing`. It was set to `No`, and I changed it to `Add to existing list`. Rebooted the router, and my computer as well. But the result was the same as before (it could not resolve the host name).

Then a noticed that the router has an option to execute commands on it, and the firmware is somehow responds to the most of linux commands. So I tried the same command on the router itself

```
> nslookup my.domain.com

Server:    127.0.0.1
Address 1: 127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain

nslookup: can't resolve 'my.domain.com'
```

Then I decided to try to look what is the DNS config and run the command:

```
> cat /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 192.168.3.1
nameserver 85.40.191.249
nameserver 85.40.191.250
```

I presume that the first one is the local DNS, the second is the one from the VPN connection and the last two are from my ISP.
Then I tried again the `nslookup` command but forced the dns server:

```
> nslookup my.domain.com 192.168.3.1

Server:    192.168.3.1
Address 1: 192.168.3.1

Name:      my.domain.com
Address 1: 192.168.3.14 my.domain.com
```

So the router resolves the dns record, but in my something with the DNS cascading (I'm not sure I use the right term) is wrong.

I have a little Linux networking knowledge, so can anyone advise, what could be the problem with this situation?

Thanks in advance,

Julian